# Writer.save() with new name python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an error when I'm trying to save an excel file with another name:

This is part of my code:

```
precios_read = pd.read_excel('Precios_{}.xls'.format(auth2), sheet_name='Precios')
precios_read = precios_read.sort_values(by=['Espacio'], ascending=True)

book = load_workbook('Template_sugerencia.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Template_sugerencia.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
precios_read.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='template', startcol=12, startrow=5, index=False, merge_cells = True)
Recom.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='template', startcol=0, startrow=5, index=False, merge_cells = True)
cliente = auth + '_' + ids
writer.save('{}.xls'.format(cliente))
```

The problem is in the last line : `writer.save('{}.xls'.format(cliente))`. If I do writer.save() only all is okey and the file was saved but if I add the name of the file I want I can't do it

`TypeError: save() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Answer (score 0):

`ExcelWriter` only takes in the filename on create, e.g.:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Template_sugerencia.xslx', engine='openpyxl')
```

`writer.save` has no arguments (the 1 argument is `self`). Calling it will save to the earlier specified filename.